# library concepts in makefiles

Tags: gcc, makefile, cygwin, gnu-make

Can anyone help me create a static library?
I'm working under cygwin and using gcc. 
I have 4 object files and I want to create a static library using `make`. How do I configure my makefile to do this?

Comment: please use the shift key when your grammar is bad it is hard for us to read your question if you want us to help you make it hard for us when you don't use punctuation to parse your text we must work extra hard for petes sake please show us that much courtesy thanku

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials out there on `make`. Read one, or more, and try for yourself. It's really not rocket science.

Comment: I agree with erkitous: [all your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/800833/karthik) seem to be about trivial concepts exposed by the length all over SO. *Please* take a look at what's already been answered, SO is not here to simply give you pre-mashed solutions. That's not the way learning is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Create a rule like this:

```
libmylibrary.a: file1.o file2.o file3.o
    ar rcs $@ $^
```

Note that you must start the second line with a Tab, not four spaces. `$@` is a special constant in the makefile that is resolved to the name of the target, while `$^` is resolved to the list of dependencies.

Comment: yeah thats right tamas but if i have 3 targets 1 target is mylibrary and other target is urlibrary and last target is exec file so how to manage all the three targets and first 2 obj files are created in mylibrary and last 2 obj files are created in ur library now the exec the target say gunn uses these 2 libraries how to make 3 targets in which 2 targets are to create libraries and one is exec files depends on these library

Comment: Well, just add three rules, two for your libraries (in the form presented above) and the third for your executable. The two libraries should be listed as dependencies for your executable.